# TypeScript: make field public only for special classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, oop, mvvm

Here's a problem. I work with pattern `MVVM`, which means I have some *Views* with display logic only and some `ViewModels` with functional logic only. `ViewModels` has methods and fields. And these fields and methods can be read or called by other ViewModel or by the `View` of `ViewModel`.

And I'd like to know, is there a way to make some fields visible only in `View`, but hidden (private) in other `ViewModels`?

I need something like this:

```js
class ViewModel1 {
  doSomething = () => {...}; // can be called anywhere

  publicForView doSomethingInView = () => {...}; // can be called only in the View

  private doSomethingInViewModel = () => {...}; // can be called only here
}

// view is a HOC-function, which joins ViewModel with View
const View1 = view(ViewModel1, ({ viewModel }) => {
  viewModel.doSomethingInView(); // can be called
  viewModel.doSomething(); // can be called
  viewModel.doSomethingInViewModel(); // can't be called

  return <div/>;
});

class ViewModel2 {
  private viewModel1: ViewModel1;

  constructor() {
    viewModel.doSomethingInView(); // can't be called
    viewModel.doSomething(); // can be called
    viewModel.doSomethingInViewModel(); // can't be called
  }
}
```

Comment: I would create two interfaces, one for view and one for the model.  Then make ViewModel implement them,.  And then just use the interface specific to each one.

Comment: Hm, looks to be a working variant. But in this case I have to write a lot of duplicate code. If I understand you, I need 2 interfaces and 1 class for every ViewModel. In this case the volume of my code base increase by 4000-5000 lines of code

Comment: Not really, it depends on how you create the interfaces.. Using Pick / Omit will keep things shorter.  I'll see if I can knock up a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a class in Typescript to expose only certain parts of a class you can create interfaces, so save on duplicate code using Pick / Omit will help in creating the interfaces.

eg..

```js
class ViewModel {
  doSomething = () => {};  
  doSomethingInView = () => {}
  doSomethingInViewModel = () => {}
}

type View = Omit<ViewModel, 'doSomethingInViewModel'>
type Model = Omit<ViewModel, 'doSomethingInView'>

function doSomethingWithView(view: View) {
    view.doSomething();
    view.doSomethingInView();
    //view.doSomethingInViewModel();  will error
}

function doSomethingWidthModel(model: Model) {
    model.doSomething();
    model.doSomethingInViewModel();
    // view.doSomethingInView(); will error
}

const view = new ViewModel();
//we can pass view to both functions, but the methods will be restricted
doSomethingWithView(view);
doSomethingWidthModel(view);
```

Working example here -> [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=29&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqCWBTA7gWQPYBNEmgbwChppN0BldAW0QBcALeAOwHNoBeaACgEp2A%20fAF8A3MSIlyVWgxYBJRghTsuvNgLyDxpCtXpNm8xWiw5lPfkIKaCNAJ4AHRHCTJlAeUrwaAHiMZsIAA00ADk2lJ6cgou-jghfDYOTrG4HB5evjEmQaHhujIG0SjxBAQAZgCujMA08OiMEjrS%20gDqXnRGnABuLgBczii8hMTEPSgAdHnNLDzC4qMuk5L5%20oYus-PQAPRbY8hLTZGFftmzxMjwILiIAE436DdWpZXVtfWNEQVtmPQpnJTZfopIabAEBA6ffQbEbQME4CErKInALQkY7aB7BHTY7rbiiC5XaC3e6PazAeoQGgYlzKRhKZE4DY7ZBOYBgBr2SAwPbQGjoaAAI3Q9GgLxqdUYEGCAoqVPoTnyWBgBNwAqcN0QlJu8BqiEwBCmRza9E6ezxBuW2O%20v1OZuEQA)

Comment: But still I have to dublicate these `doSomethingInViewModel` and `doSomethingInView`. And in cases where there will be more such fields, such code will look pretty dirty. Maybe I can mark fields I want to disable in the class?